# Array Performing XOR On Itself With Offset

Tags: swift, loops, autocorrelation

Trying to implement an autocorrelation algorithm, meaning, for example:

```
let exampleData: [Float] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Trying to find the fastest way to evaluate `1 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 3 + 3 ^ 4 + 4 ^ 5`.

Essentially, iterate through the array, and for every element, calculate the result of XOR between it and another element a set distance away.

Trouble is, this also has to be done for many different values of the offset.

Right now I just have a nested for loop, and I don't know how to make it faster...

```
var data: [Bool]
var result: [Int]

...

for offset in start..<end {
    for index in 0..<(end - offset) {
        if (data[index] ^ data[index + frequency]) {
            result[offset] += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You said “… Trouble is, this also has to be done for many different values of the offset.” What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want `windows(ofCount:)` from swift-algorithms:

https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Windows.md

That will give you a sliding window through any collection, and if your offset is relatively small (or you actually want the whole window, e.g. to do a moving average), that will be great.

The swift-algorithms stuff is nice since it's more optimized than whatever you'll do ad hoc, plus offers lazy eval.

You might also consider aligning and `zip`ping up your sequence and then mapping over that, e.g.:

```
zip(data, data.dropFirst(offset))
    .map { $0 ^ $1 }
```

...and so on

Comment: Thank you! This reduced my runtime by about 35% (the second option) - is there a way to get window or another alternative to work with an offset of more than one? From what I see it can only generate overlapping chunks.